# Relay Todo Example: Why define types 'Todo' and 'User' separately from the GraphQL version of the types?

Tags: relayjs, relay

In the [Relay Todo example](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/tree/master/todo) in '/data/database.js' the types Todo and User are created, but then in '/data/schema/nodes.js' GraphQLObjectTypes are created for each of these.

Why bother doing both and not just use the graphql types alone? Is it just to tidy the resolvers in the GraphQL definitions of these types?